# Changing Language According to Localization in java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a Project with two different languages. 
The language files work properly and 
the messages get translated when 
I click on another language.
I have added the language portlet 
on top of my portlet so that users can change 
the language whenever they want. 
so far everything perfect.
The problem: When a user is one a certain page
of the portlet and clicks on another langauge, 
he\she is redirected to the first page (view.jsp) 
of the portlet. What can I do to make the portlet
stay on the same page (jsp file) after changing
the language?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is to unspecific. What technologies are you using, how are you identifying the language?

Comment: ya..sorry .we are using servlets and jsp

Comment: so... how are you storing the language information? In the session? as a cookie? as a parameter on the URL?

Comment: i'm stroing lanuage information in the form of url-rewriting , means every page i am sending languaecode and countrycode like Test.jsp?language="en_US". it's working fine but when i am display the data some times i am calling the servlet by using Ajax to retrive  the data on that time the user select the langauge my control goes to previous page.bcz i am showing the lanuages in the form select box in my header.jsp

Comment: So I guess `sample.com/de/something` becomes `sample.com/en/something` then? In this case, is it really that hard to figure out a solution?

Comment: hi..small doubt is there anyway to change the language in jsp after select the user.without refresh the page?for example i am in en-US now user select ru-RU now i want to change the language from english to russian  without refresh the page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24583/discussion-between-12345-and-lukas-knuth)

Comment: I guess to change language you have something ,and when user select language you submit the language form, and url in that form is always the same in all page, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

you can try jstl resouce bundles for translation process.

here is reference .[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470928/jstl-resource-bundle-for-internationalization-and-localization)